# How to convert bytes to string in python

Tags: python, byte

I get the content from webpage like this

```
url = 'http://s0.icaipiao123.com/api/v2/rank/landing?lottery_key=shuangseqiu'
scode = requests.get(url).content

print(scode.decode('utf8'))

print(type(scode))

print(scode.decode())
```

The error is 
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 5: invalid continuation byte

[image]
How to convert bytes to string,thank you

Comment: Please show us your text output as text, not as a tiny scaled-down screenshot of the text.

Comment: First, why are you using `content` and then manually trying to `decode` it instead of just using `text`? Do you have reason to believe the headers are lying about the Content-Type?

Comment: Second, what makes you think that output is UTF-8 text in the first place? When I visit the same page in my browser, I get a big mess of Unicode replacement characters and square boxes with a few random letters sprinkled around. The first four bytes are all `\0`, which is a pretty good sign that, whatever this is, it isn't mean to be treated as any kind of text.

Comment: I used requests.get(url).text,return soma unicode string

Comment: Well the contents of [`http://s0.icaipiao123.com/api/v2/rank/landing?lottery_key=shuangseqiu`](http://s0.icaipiao123.com/api/v2/rank/landing?lottery_key=shuangseqiu) are not valid UTF-8 characters (try opening it in browser and see for yourself). So it cannot work. In order to convert that to a string, you have to know what it is. Maybe it simply is not a string at all.

Comment: the headers:GET http://s0.icaipiao123.com/api/v2/rank/landing?lottery_key=shuangseqiu HTTP/1.1
Host: s0.icaipiao123.com
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36 NFSBrowser/5.0.4.2020
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8

Comment: I don't understand your problem. If `requests.get(url).text` returns some Unicode string, and what you want is some Unicode string, then you're done. But I don't see how it could be a _useful_ Unicode string, given that, again, the first four bytes are all 0's, so this is almost certainly not text. So I don't know what output you were hoping to decode this to.

Comment: In fact ,It returns a json.But I don't know how to decode it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import codecs  
#scode data variable
codecs.decode(scode, 'UTF-8')
```